# CSS height not being applied unless I use inline styling

Tags: css, nativescript

I have 3 buttons

```
<Button row="0" col="0" text="1" class="nums" style="height: 100;"/>
<Button row="0" col="1" text="2" class="nums"/>
<Button row="0" col="2" text="3" class="nums"/>
```

I can only get the height to change if I use inline style as button 1, button 2 and 3 rely on the app.css file and ignores the height although the other styles are applied.

```
.nums{
  android-elevation: 4;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  border-color: darkolivegreen;
  border-radius: 10;
  border-width: 5;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-size: 24;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 100;
  width: 100;
}
```

[image]

Comment: 100 what? Centimers, pixels, or percentage of parent? It needs a unit to work.

Comment: I was wondering that as well apparently nativescript doesn't require units. [Nativescript Styling](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling)

Comment: Are you able to inspect your page? Your `height` and `width` might get overridden by a higher [specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp). Inline code basically overrides everything that is not `!important`. Another class `.nums` which gets processed after your code might interfer.

Comment: @AlexG Hit the nail on the head. A default app imports two CSS files that appear to be overriding the custom CSS even though the custom CSS is last in the list.

Comment: @FrankNicklin sweet, glad i could help! I've posted a little more detailed answer based on my comment for you to accept!

Comment: Yes, the {N} theme sets height on the buttons as a workaround for an Android problem with changing button height depending on if there is a border property set (and border-radius is one of them). I think the specificity is 11, so you can override it with an Element.class or .class.other-class for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `height` and `width` might get overridden by a higher *[specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp)*. Inline code basically overrides everything that is not `!important`, due to the increased *specificity*.

Also classes with the same *specificity* will get overridden when declared again after the first declaration. For example another class named `.nums` which gets processed after your code might interfer.

Simply appending your styles after the framework CSS or loading your custom CSS file after the framework CSS should do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, do not sentence case your element definitions: i.e: `<button>` not `<Button>`.

Your problem is easily solved:

`<button row="0" col="0" text="1" class="nums" style="height: 100px;"/>` <-- note the px added.

Comment: <Button> capitalised is how NativeScript Playground defines its objects. NativeScript does not require units as the height can be determined without units. adding px does increase the height, but not the same as inline style="height:100"